# how to solve Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3

Tags: java

So here im trying to modify my arraylist by making a function call find data here is the code

```
    private int findData (VaccineName vaccineType, VaccinationCentre vaccineCentre, int vaccineStock){
            for(int i =0; i<DataIO.vaccine.size();i++){
                Vaccine cd = DataIO.vaccine.get(i);
                if(cd.getVaccineType().equals(vaccineType) && cd.getVaccineCentre().equals(vaccineCentre)&& cd.getVaccineStock()==(vaccineStock)){
                    System.out.println(i + " find data int");
                    return i;
                }  
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

so in the out put when I choose from the j table it just keeps saying that the position is 0 then here is my query code

```
public Vaccine queryData(VaccineName vaccineType, VaccinationCentre vaccineCentre, int vaccineStock){
        int position = findData(vaccineType, vaccineCentre, vaccineStock);
        if(position > 0){
            System.out.println(DataIO.vaccine.get(position));
            return DataIO.vaccine.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and I keep getting an error saying

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 4
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:473)
at VaccineHome.jButton5ActionPerformed(VaccineHome.java:430)
at VaccineHome$8.actionPerformed(VaccineHome.java:160)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

here is my modify code

```
for(int i = 0; i<DataIO.vaccine.size(); i++){
                    String vaccineName = tfVaccineType.getText();
                    VaccineName vaccineType = VaccineName.valueOf(vaccineName);
                    String vaccineCentre = tfVaccineCentre.getText();
                    VaccinationCentre vc = VaccinationCentre.valueOf(vaccineCentre);
                    int stock = (Integer)vaccineSpinner.getValue();
                    Vaccine v = new Vaccine(vaccineType, vc,stock);
                    Vaccine cz = queryData(DataIO.vaccine.get(i).getVaccineType(),DataIO.vaccine.get(i).getVaccineCentre(),DataIO.vaccine.get(i).getVaccineStock());
                    int found = findData(cz);        
                    DataIO.vaccine.set(found, v);
                    DataIO.write();
                    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)tableVaccine.getModel();
                    tableModel.setNumRows(0);
                    viewTable();
                    System.out.println(DataIO.vaccine.toString());
                }
```

can anyone help me with this problem thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it is in this place when you suspect? Can you post full stacktrace? In fact, you can see in stacktrace exactly where is source of this exception.

Comment: okey sir , i will post

Comment: Are you sure that you got the exception from this version of queryData method? Since you have that guard there... without seeing the whole project and file names etc, it's really difficult to make really sense about the stacktrace

Comment: The stack trace is telling you that you passed -1 to DataIO.vaccine.set.  Perhaps you should print the value of `found` after calling findData.